# What is the difference between training function and learning function

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

What is the difference between Training function and learning function in
Artificial Neural Network ?
I have found [this](http://www.mathworks.com/products/neural-network/description4.html) , but can't understand properly.
Would anybody please explain ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The training function is the overall algorithm that is used to train the neural network to recognize a certain input and map it to an output. A common example is [backpropagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) and its many variations and weight/bias training. A learning function deals with individual weights and thresholds and decides how those would be manipulated. These usually (but not always) employ some form of [gradient descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent). Examples include [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing), [Silva and Almeida's algorithm](http://www.lx.it.pt/~lbalmeida/papers/AlmeidaHNC.pdf), using [momentum](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs449/Momentum/momentum.html) and [adaptive learning-rates](http://www.math.upatras.gr/~dgs/papers/reports/tr98-02.pdf), and weight-learning (examples include [Hebb](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15782-f06/slides/hebbpca.pdf), [Kohonen](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~jlw/sem2a2/Web/Kohonen.htm), etc.) algorithms.

Comment: It seems that you understand the difference between training and learning function. Can you present extra details?
I have a question about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62333003/2316663